# Draw a line in a circular path in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to draw a line in circular path where this line's length should increase ( from 0 to the complete circle circumference) while it is moving in that circular path.
Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Canvas`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) :

```
Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    width: 200
    height: 200
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

You can find explanation about the `arc` method in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#arc-method): you simply need to define `startAngle` and `endAngle` in your QML and update them when you want to move or increase the line.